# How to enable asset browser in Add Related Item dialog?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, task-list, team-sites, assets

When I click the "ADD RELATED ITEM" link in a task item view (standard task list on standard team site, SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise):

[image: Add Related Item Link in task item view]

I get a very simple "Type URL" dialog, which is not very user friendly:

[image: Type URL dialog]

But according to several articles ([1](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/new-sharepoint-2013-column-related-items), [2](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/09/14/sharepoint-2013-related-items-site-column/)  and [3](http://mysharepointt.blogspot.dk/2013/07/related-items-column-sharepoint-2013.html)) I am supposed to get a nice asset browser dialog like this:

[image: Select An Asset]

How do I get this asset browser dialog instead of the simple "Type URL" dialog?

EDIT:
According to [this discussion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/bbb4cd2e-28a5-4c17-9c28-f590edcd86bd/error-and-unexpected-popup-when-using-related-items-site-column?forum=sharepointgeneral), the dialog difference is related to SharePoint Edition:

- The simple "Type URL" dialog comes with Foundation
- The rich "Select an Asset" dialog comes with Server

I'm running Server Enterprise (w. latest april 2017 cu). Why do I still get that scraped dialog then?